# Visual C++ get path and filename to TextBox

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I want display full path + name + extension of image file to Visual C++ TextBox (Windows Form),  when i try to build that, it's failed:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Testing, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Testing.cpp
1>Testing.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000003) Testing.Form1::GetFileName
1>c:\users\febri nur hidayat\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Testing\Debug\Testing.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

here is my source code :

```
private: System::Void textBox1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    if(openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK){
        this->pictureBox1->Image = Image::FromFile(openFileDialog1->FileName);
        String^ sourceImage;
        citra = Path::GetFileName(openFileDialog1->FileName);
        this->textBox1->Text = sourceImage;
    }
}
```

any advice or what should i code?

Comment: No need to call `GetFileName`. Just do this: `this->textBox1->Text = openFileDialog1->FileName`

Comment: still not working, fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals. :(